# Generics without collection

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that usually takes an item from a list and has a signature of:

```
myMethod(T item)
```

I want to use this method but I know what I am sending the method.

```
SpecificItem myItem = new SpecificItem();

myMethod((T) myItem);
```

This doesn't sit well with me.  Is this a sign of bad code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myMethod` is defined in a generic class, somewhat like:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   T myItem;

   public void myMethod(T item) {
      // do Something with item
   }

   public T myOtherMethod() {
      myMethod(myItem);   // casting is not necessary
      return myItem;
   }

}
```

If you instantiate this class, you exchange the variable type `T` with a real one:

```
MyClass<SpecificItem > concreteClass = new MyClass<SpecificItem >();
```

And if you call `myMethod` on this instance, you have to provide a `SpecificItem`, because `SpecificItem` is the generic type for this instance.

<sup>(I'm not sure it my post answers your question, please comment so I can improve it)</sup>

Comment: So if I have 

public interface myInterface<T>{
   void myMethod(T item);
}
both T's have to match??

Comment: @Lumpy, yes, that's why they are both named "T". If you wanted multiple types, you could do myInterface<T,S> or so forth (see, e.g., Map)

Answer (score 2):

It's better that you code to interface. For example :

In myMethod :

```
<T extends <? super Item>> void (T item);
```

This tells compiler to only accepts a generic type of T which is an implementation/extention of Item interface/class. This will make sure that given input is in correct type. Compiler guarantees it.

In main class :

```
Item myItem = new SpecificItem();
```

Code given above is the best practice. Get used to it. But (i discourage this) you can code like this too :

```
SpecificItem myItem = new SpecificItem();
```

You can read Java source code. For example in class java.util.Collections. In method [sort(List)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) you may notice that Joshua Bloch makes sure that given input is always in correct format. To give it a try, do this :

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class1> list = new ArrayList<Class1>();

        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

Above code will produce compilation error. To fix this compilation error Class1 must implement interface Comparable. This maintains the precondition of method sort(List) which assumes that given input is a List of Comparable.

Oh i almost forget about your question. Actually it's not a bad code since it works. I just want to tell you that there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
class C<? extends T> {

   public void myMethod(T myItem) {
      ...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you call the method looks strange. If you have declared your generic method as

```
public <T> void myMethod(T item);
```

the compiler knows, that T is some abstract type and you shouldn't need to cast an input parameter to it. Just make sure, that T is not declared as some specific type in your code.

upd: look here for an example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0200__Generics/Usinggenericmethodstoprintarrayofdifferenttypes.htm

Comment: this is equivalent to `public void myMethod(Object item);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably better way would be to make SpecificItem a subclass of T or make T an interface and have SpecificItem implement it.